# Spring Kafka Simple Producer and Consumer with Retries and DLQ

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Can someone create a simple spring kafka program with Producer and Consumer on Java. It should have retries and dead letter queue.

Answer (score 1):

See the samples: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/tree/main/samples

- sample-01 - simple producer/consumer with dead-letter topic
- sample-02 - multi-method listener
- sample-03 - transactions
- sample-04 - topic based (non-blocking) retry